# retrieve data from sqldatasource object

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I'm working on a gridview and got a little problem with the built in edit button.

the gridview got 3 columns title, artist, genre and when editing the genre a ddl shows.

in my grv_update event

```
 protected void grv_Update(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        //get old and new values
        var oldArtistName = e.OldValues["Artist"].ToString();
        var oldTitle = e.OldValues["Title"].ToString();
        var oldGenre = e.OldValues["Genre"].ToString();            
        int songId = Convert.ToInt16(e.Keys["ID"]);

        var newArtistName = e.NewValues["Artist"].ToString().Trim();
        var newTitle = e.NewValues["Title"].ToString().Trim();
        var newGenre = e.NewValues["Genre"].ToString();
    }
```

I'm able to retrieve the old and new values of the edited line.

My Problem is if i want to store the changes in my database i need the genreId instead of the genre(name). So is there anyway to retrieve the genreId from my sqldatasource without having to connect to the db?

my select command looks like this:

```
select tblSong.ID ,Title, Artist, Genre from tblSong JOIN tblArtist on ArtistId = tblArtist.ID
        JOIN tblGenre on GenreId = tblGenre.ID;
```

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

How does the user specify the Genre in the GridView? A DropDownList? Then set the text of the ListItem to the GenreName and the value to the GenreId.

If you're not using a DropDownList, you need to provide us with more details about your GridView.

Comment: its a ddl, ill try this